# Executar uma página dentro de uma tela modal jquery por ajax sem IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp

É possível executar uma página que esteja dentro de meu `dir`, dentro de um modal sem `IFrame` por `ajax`? Se sim, como eu faria isso? No momento minhas páginas teriam esse caminho: `../../GEN/asp/pagina.asp?parâmetros=`

Esse seria meu modal:

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Abaixo a minha função jquery atual, que não está funcionando corretamente.

```
var dialog = $("#dialog");
    var openModal = $("#btnLupa");

    dialog.dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
    });

    dialog.load(function () {
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });

    var AbrirModal = function (url, title, width, height) {
        dialog.dialog("option", "width", width);
        dialog.dialog("option", "height", height);
        dialog.dialog("option", "title", title);
        dialog.attr("src", url);
    }
```

Essa é a minha chamada atual à função jquery

```
<img id='btnLupa' style='display:; cursor:hand' name='Pesquisa_Contrato' width='16' height='16' src='/gen/mid/lupa.gif' border='0' alt='Pesquisa Contrato' onclick='AbrirModal("http://amlsp1844/GEN/ASP/GEN0001a.asp?ind_situacao=&tipo_empresa=&ind_classificacao=&p_cod_tipo_contrato=&indsubmit=false&txt_nome_campo_cod=num_contrato&txt_nome_campo_cod_ts=cod_ts_contrato&txt_nome_campo_desc=nome_contrato&ind_tipo_pessoa=J&funcao_executar=PesquisaContratoMontaFilial();&abre_modal=N&ind_alteracao_contrato=&tipo_preco=", "Pesquisa Contrato", 480, 360)'>
```

Esse é o que eu tenho agora, mas posso jogar tudo pro alto e refazer coisas novas, mas não tenho idéia. Com `IFrame` está dando pau e gostaria de abandonar o `IFrame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, quanto a esse post eu resolvi. Como? Quanto ao ajax sem IFrame, tive que abandonar, pois tenho que continuar a usar o IFrame. E para resolver o problema do IFrame que estava dando, no meu caso aqui, teria que chamar uma nova página antes de chamar a página necessária. Dessa forma vocês não teriam como ajudar e nem sabia disso. Um cara aqui descobriu sem querer. Valeu e dentro de 2 dias encerro o post.

Comment: Dê uma procurada sobre a função load()